# pyspark lead operation for creating time intervals

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

| time |
| --- |
| First |
| Second |
| Third |

I would like to have an output like this using Pyspark, where I create an interval with the row itself and its subsequent row:

| time | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | First | Second |
| Second | Second | Third |
| Third | ... | .... |

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to order the dataframe by `time` variable, then you need to create a `monotonically_increasing_id` to create a `lead` column over an ordered window.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().orderBy('id')

df \
  .sort('time') \
  .withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
  .withColumn('start', F.col('time')) \
  .withColumn('end', F.lead(F.col('time')).over(w)) \
  .drop('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Can avoid creating more columns and the pain of dropping them by using last and lead in window functions

```
w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('time')
df =df.withColumn('Start', last('time').over(w)).withColumn('End', lead('time').over(w))

df.show()
```